# Rhino Mocks receive argument, modify it and return?

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
myStub.Stub(_ => _.Create(Arg<Invoice>.It.Anything)).Callback(i => { i.Id = 100; return i; });
```

I want to get actual object that passed to mock, modify it and return back.

Is this scenario possible with Rhino Mocks?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could use the `WhenCalled` method like this:

```
myStub
    .Stub(_ => _.Create(Arg<Invoice>.Is.Anything))
    .Return(null) // will be ignored but still the API requires it
    .WhenCalled(_ => 
    {
        var invoice = (Invoice)_.Arguments[0];
        invoice.Id = 100;
        _.ReturnValue = invoice;
    });
```

and then you can create your stub as such:

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice { Id = 5 };
Invoice result = myStub.Create(invoice);
// at this stage result = invoice and invoice.Id = 100
```

Comment: You can avoid the call to Return() by adding IgnoreArguments() on the end I think.

Comment: @samjudson: Rhino still throws an exception without Return even with IgnoreArguments, so Return is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had no need to add IgnoreArguments() to avoid using Return(). 
This is my original method:

```
List<myEntity> GetDataByRange(int pageSize, int offsetRecords);
```

Here is my mock example:

```
_Repository.Stub(x => x.GetDataByRange(Arg<int>.Is.Anything, Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
           .WhenCalled(x => {
                              var mylist = entitiesList?.Skip((int)x.Arguments[1])?
                                                  .Take((int)x.Arguments[0])?.ToList();
                              x.ReturnValue = mylist;   
                            });
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that Rhino Mocks 4.0.0+ doesn't require a `.Return()` to be called before `.WhenCalled()` invocation. But it only works for methods stubbing. If we stub an *Indexer* it still require the `.Return()` to be used before `.WhenCalled()`.